# Principal component Analysis using median as the center

Tags: r, regression, logistic, pca, data-visualization

Please I’m performing an analysis which requires data reduction technique.  After preliminary analysis the data is suitable for principal component analysis and I’m comfortable using R but I want to introduce median as the center of the data instead of the usual mean but I’m getting the codes wrong can anyone be of help to me?

Comment: You may take any point you like as the pivot point for the PCA. But you should be cautious. Results strongly depend on the pivot point chosen. You must have a PCA function that has an option to do it without initial data transform such as centering or standardization. You will manually transform yourself, in your case, that will be to deviations from the median. Then submit to that PCA function, not allowing it to do any transforms.

Comment: Thanks for your take on this @ttnphns